# Calculate the number of Month based on the Dates Entered in Textboxes

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform in which three textboxes are there.
Textbox1 belongs to Start date
Textbox2 belongs to  End Date
Textbox3 belongs to No of Months.

Below is my code.

```
Dim mon As Integer

'Check Whether the Start Date Text Box is Empty or Not
If IsNull(Me.TextBox1.Text) = True Then
Me.TextBox3.Value = ""

Else
Me.TextBox2.Value = Format(DateAdd("yyyy", 1, Me.TextBox1.Value) - 1, "dd-mmm-yyyy")

mon = DateDiff("m", Me.TextBox1, Me.TextBox2)
Me.TextBox3.Value = mon

End If
```

The above code calculates the end date and no. of months. The problem is when i enter the 1st date of any month, it shows me only 11 months. However, if i enter any other date except 1st, it shows 12 months.

Please advise me how can i get 12 months if i enter the 1st date of any month.

Thanks
Salman

Comment: Why you minus 1 day in `TextBox2`? 01-Oct - 1 will be 30-Sep, and there are only 11 months from Oct-2018 to Sep-2019. If you do need the `- 1`, then add it back in `DateDiff`.

Comment: I did minus one so that end date will come one day back as of start date. i.e if i have entered start date as 01-09-2018 then end date should come 31-08-2018. For this reason, i did minus 1. However if i add 1 again in datediff, it exceeds the number of months to 13.

Comment: Well, I don't get a 13 for my testing. However since the input of `TextBox2` is not from the user, why don't you just assign `12` to `TextBox3` :P

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tested this code and it works nice:

```
Sub Test()

Dim mon As Integer

'Check Whether the Start Date Text Box is Empty or Not
If IsNull(Cells(4, 3).Text) = True Then
Cells(5, 3).Value = ""

Else
Cells(4, 4).Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, Cells(4, 3).Value - 1)
Cells(4, 4).NumberFormat = "d-mmm-yyyy"

mon = DateDiff("m", Cells(4, 3), Cells(4, 4) + 1)
Cells(5, 3).Value = mon

End If


End Sub
```

When Format function was used, I couldn't just add 1 day in DateDiff. It is because you can't add 1 to a string, I guess.

```
Sub Test2()
Dim xDate As Long
Dim xNewDate As Long

xDate = 40179  'It is 01.01.2010
xNewDate = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, xDate - 1)

xDateFormat = Format(xDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
xNewDateFormat = Format(xNewDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy")


MsgBox DateDiff("m", xDate, xNewDate + 1)

Debug.Print xDate
Debug.Print Format(xDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
Debug.Print xNewDate
Debug.Print Format(xNewDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy")

Debug.Print ""

'Debug.Print CLng(xDateFormat)                                                                 'Type Mismatch
'Debug.Print CLng(xNewDateFormat)                                                              'Type Mismatch
Debug.Print DateDiff("m", xDateFormat, xNewDateFormat)                                         'It works so DateDiff converts it
Debug.Print DateDiff("m", DateDiff("d", 0, xDateFormat), DateDiff("d", 0, xNewDateFormat) + 1) 'Now you can add one day


End Sub
```

I hope that this code should work:

```
Dim mon As Integer

'Check Whether the Start Date Text Box is Empty or Not
If IsNull(Me.TextBox1.Text) = True Then
Me.TextBox3.Value = ""

Else
Me.TextBox2.Value = Format(DateAdd("yyyy", 1, Me.TextBox1.Value) - 1, "dd-mmm-yyyy")

mon = DateDiff("m", Me.TextBox1, Me.TextBox2)
mon = DateDiff("m", DateDiff("d", 0, Me.TextBox1), DateDiff("d", 0, Me.TextBox2) + 1)
Me.TextBox3.Value = mon

End If
```